# java 7 socket listen exception

Tags: java, sockets, java-7, java-6

I have java 7 socket listen exception during jboss initialization.

```
JAVA: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\\bin\java

17:14:15,388 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:8083/
17:14:15,405 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss:service=WebService state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: listen failed
```

When I set JAVA_HOME to `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0.26` there are no exceptions during jboss initialization.

Comment: What is JAVA_HOME set to then?

Answer (score 2):

My *guess* is that this is Windows firewall - that it's got an exception (i.e. a permission) for the JDK 6 binary, but not for the JDK 7 binary. I suggest you open up the Windows firewall configuration applet, check what's there (either by port or binary) and give JDK 7 the same permission.

EDIT: I suggest you get JBoss out of the equation: write a small app which simply tries to listen on port 8083 on 127.0.0.1. Try running that on both JDK6 and JDK7. If that *works* in both out of the box, then try varying *exactly* how you specify the listening port.

Comment: Windows firewall is disabled, it definitely does not make any impact. I have also Outpost Firewall installed, but when I tested, its service was terminated also. I would try to check rules in outpost.